# Issue accessing qgis.core module from separate Python file

Tags: pyqgis, nameerror

I have a few python scripts I would like to call from the QGIS Python console. It was working well until I attempted to separate some of the functions to another file -- the qgis.core modules are not available to the separate file.

Here's some of the code to explain what I mean. All of the files are in a folder called pyQgis:

```
from qgis.core import *
import sys
scripts = "..//pyQgis"
sys.path.append (scripts)

from other_file import get_elem

test = QgsProject.instance()
print(test)

test_run = get_elem("cable_ht")
```

other_file.py

```
from qgis.core import *

def get_elem(layer_name):
    proj = QgsProject.instance()
```

The variable 'test' prints out okay. But the instance from the other file gives:

```
NameError: name 'QgsProject' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing the *other_file* module (which include its `from qgis.core import *` line), but only its *get_elem* name definition, in a separate namespace in which *QgsProject* name is just not defined.

You can solve it in some ways. Depending on your package structure they can work or not. For instance:

```
# Import the module from a relative path
from . import other_file

# Call its function
test_run = other_file.get_elem("cable_ht")
```